# DynamoDBMapper - performance and best practice

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

Are there any performance hits in using the DynamoDBMapper over the low level APIs? I'd imagine there'd be minimal to insignificant performance overheads but I'm not able to find any references online that says this.

Also the examples online show the mapper annotations used on the POJO itself. Is this best practice or would it be better to have the POJO untouched and a separate mapper used to take in the POJO to do the save, query, update etc. The advantage I see with the latter is that if/when you replace DynamoDB with another database it will be a cleaner refactor by having the extra layer of abstraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first point, you most likely won't see any significant performance difference because it is just doing some annotation processing and caches them to reduce further reflection on classes that it has already seen. The best thing to do would be to actually benchmark it, but I think you will find that it is negligible.

To your second point, I would say that "it depends" based on how you want to model your data access. If you do, however, choose to go the route of abstracting your POJOs you have to be careful about your annotations because of the way the mapper processes them. I have ran into problems before (about a year ago) where the parent class was not annotated with `@Table` and the child class the mapper struggled to pull out the correct annotation.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I agree with your second point. Having thought a little more I think it would depend on how different the POJO and the new class used for the mapper would be. A project I worked on actually had quite a lot of differences and so we went ahead with the additional layer of abstraction and so it made sense there. Otherwise I think it's fine to use the POJO with the annotations.